# Hover effect wait for ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem in jQuery: I have a mouseOver and mouseOut effect on a div for expanding and collapsing addtocart button, but I need a functionality, if click on addtocart button inside the div then i need to stop mouseout effect and keep that div expanded until the item gets response from a ajax call to add it to basket, and  once ajax call is complete then only apply mouseout effect.

Thanks in advance. Here is what i have so far:

[image]

```js
 $('.productitem').mouseover(function () {
                $(this).find('.productparams:first').stop().slideUp();
                $(this).find('.addtocart:first').stop().fadeTo(100, 1);
            })
                .mouseout(function () {
                $(this).find('.productparams:first').stop().slideDown();
                $(this).find('.addtocart:first').stop().fadeTo(100, 0);
            });
            
            
 //button click code
function _addBtnClick(event) {        
        var ctrl = $(this).parent('.productitem');
        ctrl.unbind('mouseout');
        
        //this calls ajax
        _addToCart.call(this);
    }
```

Here is sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Grmej/1/
The only change is that onclick i am calling ajax and on completing ajax call, i need to fire mouseout.

Comment: @kenef : formatted now.

Comment: @TheUnKnown : i think it was a simple html, so i provided screen shot. productitem class is external div and addtocart is button class.

Comment: You literally just need to use a Promise call back like `.done()` this is basic ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if click on addtocart button inside the div then i need to stop mouseout effect and keep that div expanded until the item gets response from a ajax call

The AJAX call and the jQuery need to coordinate the start and stop of the animations. Here is a snippet that shows the basic interactions.

```js
function mouseOver() {
    $(this).find('.productparams:first').stop().slideUp();
    $(this).find('.addtocart:first').stop().fadeTo(100, 1);
}

function mouseOut() {
    $(this).find('.productparams:first').stop().slideDown();
    $(this).find('.addtocart:first').stop().fadeTo(100, 0);
}

function toggle(show) {
  if (show) {
    $('.productitem').mouseover(mouseOver).mouseout(mouseOut);
  } else {
    $('.productitem').off('mouseover', mouseOver).off('mouseout', mouseOut);
  }
}
            
$(".addtocart").click(_addBtnClick);            

//button click code
function _addBtnClick() {    
    var ctrl = $(this).parent().get(0);
    
    // stop animations
    toggle(false);
    
    // setup fade out
    $('.addtocart').delay(3000).fadeTo(100, 0);
    
    //this calls ajax
    _addToCart(ctrl);
}

function _addToCart(item) {
  // simulate ajax wait
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    var title = $(item).find("span").text();
    console.log(title + " added to cart");
    
    // start animations
    toggle(true);
  }, 6000);
}

// setup
$(document).find('.addtocart').stop().fadeTo(100, 0);
toggle(true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: flex;flex-direction:row">
  <div class="productitem" style="width:70px;height:90px;border:1px solid teal;padding:3px;margin:2px;">
    <span>Item One</span>
    <div class="productparams">Color</div>
    <button class="addtocart">Add to cart</button>
  </div>

  <div class="productitem" style="width:70px;height:90px;border:1px solid teal;padding:3px;margin:2px;">
    <span>Item Two</span>
    <div class="productparams">Color</div>
    <button class="addtocart">Add to cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Christopher Taleck - Seems very very close, the only problem is that when i click on 'add to cart' button and hover out then the button doesn't fades away after 3 seconds. I have to hover again on it.

Comment: I adjusted the snippet to handle the fade out. Hopefully, the snippet gives you enough of an idea on how to handle the various events. You'll just have to fiddle with it until it is to your satisfaction. Accept if this has been helpful.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what i was trying to do. Thanks much for help!